# How to diagnose WSL error in Docker Desktop?

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I just installed Docker Desktop for Win 10 which historically has worked just fine. When I installed it this time I'm seeing this error message at startup

[image: An unexpected error was encountered while executing a WSL command]

> **Unexpected WSL error**
> An unexpected error was encountered while
> executing a WSL command. Common causes include access rights issues,
> which occur after waking the computer or not being connected to your
> domain/active directory.  Please try shutting WSL down (`wsl --shutdown`) and/or rebooting your computer. If not sufficient, WSL may need to be reinstalled fully. As a last resort, try to
> uninstall/reinstall Docker Desktop. If the issue persists please
> collect diagnostics and submit an issue
> (https://docs.docker.com/desktop/troubleshoot/overview/#diagnose-from-the-terminal).

For the installation I followed these steps:

- Checked that virtualization technology is enabled in BIOS
- Enabled Windows Subsystem for Linux
- Enabled Virtual Machine Platform
- ran [linux kernel update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual#step-4---download-the-linux-kernel-update-package) (said a newer version was installed)
- ran wsl --set-default-version 2
- installed docker desktop

After clicking out of the error message I have about 5 seconds to look at any settings before docker desktop automatically shuts down. I've been dealing with this for hours and I'm stumped. Running wsl --shutdown, restart, or reinstalling have not helped.

Comment: One of the things that docker suggests doing in that help document is running the [self-diagnose tool](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/troubleshoot/overview/#self-diagnose-tool), which runs a bunch of checks. Do any of those checks fail?

Comment: You mentioned that you've tried reinstalling - did you reinstall Docker Desktop, WSL, or both?

Comment: @NickODell tried running that. It opens & closes within a millisecond, doesn't provide any feedback or new files. I tried reinstalling both